# Why does jPlayer fire the pause event at the end of a track play

Tags: javascript, jplayer

We are using JPlayer 2.9.2, with a very basic prototype (see code snippet below).

When a track ends the 'pause' event is being fired and then the 'ended' event in chrome, where as in Firefox, only the 'pause' event is fired.

Can any anyone explain why this is the case?

We spiked this prototype because in our production code we are seeing similarly confusing behaviour. Such as 'pause' is firing on mobiles and 'ended' is firing on desktops.

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.9.2/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "Bubble",
            m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
            oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
          });
        },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "m4a, oga",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true,
  ended : function(){
   var sam = 1;
  },
  pause : function(){
   var sam = 2;
  },
  
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" role="application" aria-label="media player">
  <div class="jp-type-single">
    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
      <div class="jp-volume-controls">
        <button class="jp-mute" role="button" tabindex="0">mute</button>
        <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max volume</button>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-controls-holder">
        <div class="jp-controls">
          <button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
          <button class="jp-stop" role="button" tabindex="0">stop</button>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-label="time">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-label="duration">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="jp-toggles">
          <button class="jp-repeat" role="button" tabindex="0">repeat</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-details">
      <div class="jp-title" aria-label="title">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-no-solution">
      <span>Update Required</span>
      To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Dan. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I raised a bug on GitHub too. Thoughts?

Comment: Not off top of my head. According to the source code, FireFox should also be firing 'Ended'. I'm going to test it later when I have time. Can you link the github link?
The pause event is fired because otherwise a click on the progress bar will play from that point, when it shouldn't, since it stopped playback (Taken from comments in src code). So that should happen.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it, and it's working for me. Which Firefox version are you using?

- Chrome: Paused -> Ended.
- FireFox: Ended -> Paused.

http://jsfiddle.net/chq6uu16/13/

Source code jPlayer:

```
 mediaElement.addEventListener("ended", function () {
                if (entity.gate) {
                    // Order of the next few commands are important. Change the time and then pause.
                    // Solves a bug in Firefox, where issuing pause 1st causes the media to play from the start. ie., The pause is ignored.
                    if (!$.jPlayer.browser.webkit) { // Chrome crashes if you do this in conjunction with a setMedia command in an ended event handler. ie., The playlist demo.
                        self.htmlElement.media.currentTime = 0; // Safari does not care about this command. ie., It works with or without this line. (Both Safari and Chrome are Webkit.)
                    }
                    self.htmlElement.media.pause(); // Pause otherwise a click on the progress bar will play from that point, when it shouldn't, since it stopped playback.
                    self._updateButtons(false);
                    self._getHtmlStatus(mediaElement, true); // With override true. Otherwise Chrome leaves progress at full.
                    self._updateInterface();
                    self._trigger($.jPlayer.event.ended);
                }
            }, false);
```

It looks like the different ordering in which being fired first is necessary browser fix.

Also, I have listened to that 'Miaow-07-Bubble' so many times I now really like it :P.